# Error getting value from 'ServerVersion' on 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

The Environment:

Visual Studio 2012 Professional and SQL Server Express 2012 (localhost\sqlexpress)

Here's my connection string:

`Server=localhost\sqlexpress;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=True;Connection Timeout=30;`

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to serialize an object using the Newtsonsoft Json Serialzer.

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("user", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MasterData.User));`

This is the error that I'm getting:

`Error getting value from 'ServerVersion' on 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.`

Don't worry about the MasterData.User object. It's a custom object that has a SqlConnection as part of its base class. This is where it's failing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using async? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.serverversion.aspx says it can throw when the connection is closed.

Comment: I basically have a method that returns to me a `SqlConnection`. Something like `return MyApplication.NewSqlConnection()`.

When I return the connection, I don't open it all. I just return the connection. The calling function will use the connection and open it, but at that time, the connection has already been created.

I'm not calling async explicitly unless the .NET Framework calls it behind the scenes.

Comment: How do you use this connection though? Your post is missing this part.

Comment: I use it normally `SqlConnection conn = myApplication.NewSqlConnection();` followed by `conn.Open();` I haven't tested this yet, but I'm thinking that after reading your link more carefully, I might only be able to retrieve the server version while the connection is open, which is why the JsonConvert.SerializeObject method is throwing an exception - because it sees the property of ServerVersion, but is not able to serialize it because it is not accessible while the connection is closed.

Comment: Assuming that I'm correct (with the statement above), I ended up solving it myself. I originally had the `MyApplication.NewSqlConnection()` as a property, so it was like this: `MyApplication.DBConnection`. Because it was a property, the JsonConvert.SerializeObject method was trying to serialize it. When I converted it to a function `MyApplication.NewSqlConnection()`, it solved the problem because NewtonSoft doesn't serialize functions. Problem solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it.